# How can I pack a kivy python script to IPA app for iOS?

Tags: python, ios, kivy, ipa

I have  a kivy python script that already packed into apk and runs successfully, how can I pack it into ipa so I can install it in iOS?

My OS: windows10

Thanks.

Comment: You will need a Mac https://realpython.com/mobile-app-kivy-python/#packaging-your-app-for-ios

Comment: Is there anyway I can work with on Windows?

Comment: Well, you can try and use a Hackintosh VM. You need access to the Xcode toolchain that is only available for macOS.